# Find two vectors $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I feel like I don't have enough information to solve this question:

> Find two vectors $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ whose sum is $\{3, -5, 1\}$ where $\vec{v_1}$ is parallel to $\{4, 3, 3\}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ is perpendicular to $\{4, 3, 3\}$.

We know $k\cdot \{4, 3, 3\} = \vec{v_1} \ $ and $\ \{4, 3, 3\} \cdot \vec{v_2} = 0$, but when I try to substitute everything, I just end up getting $0 = 0$. I tried to find the component of $\{3, -5, 1\}$  in the direction $\{4, 3, 3\}$ with a projection, but since $\{3, -5, 1\}\cdot \{4, 3, 3\}$ gives $0 \ $ I keep running into a wall.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Then that means you’ve found $v_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{a} = (4, 3, 3)$

Let's start with:
$$\vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2} = (3, -5, 1)$$

Multiply both sides by $\vec{a}$:
$$\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2}) = (3, -5, 1) \cdot \vec{a}$$
$$\implies \vec{a} \cdot \vec{v_1} + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{v_2} = (3, -5, 1) \cdot (4, 3, 3)$$

Since $(3, -5, 1) \cdot (4, 3, 3) = (0, 0, 0)$, $\vec{v_2}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ (meaning $\vec{v_2} \cdot \vec{a} = 0$) and $\vec{v_1}$ is parallel to $\vec{a}$ (meaning $\vec{v_1} = k \cdot \vec{a}$, where $k$ is a real constant), we get:
$$k \cdot \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} = (0, 0, 0)$$

This leads to $k = 0$, which implies $\vec{v_1} = (0, 0, 0)$. From here you can get $\vec{v_2} = (3, -5, 1)$

Answer (score 0):

You might neglect that the zero vector is parallel to any vector.So based on your idea,$(3-4k,-5-3k,1-3k)\cdot(4,3,3)=0$,then we can find that $k=0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:
$\vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2} = \{3, -5, 1\} \implies x_1+x_2= 3, \ y_1+y_2=-5, \, z_1+z_2=1$.
$\vec{v_1} \parallel \{4,3,3\} \implies x_1=4k, \ y_1=3k, \ z_1=3k, \ k\in \mathbb{R}$.
$\vec{v_2} \perp \{4,3,3\} \implies 4x_2+3y_2+3z_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that the sum of $v_1$ and $v_2$ (denote it by $w$) is perpendicular to $(4,3,3)$ which is perpendicular to $v_2$, this implies that $v_2 \parallel w$. So $w=v_2+0$ where the zero vector is $v_1$, since zero vector is parallel to any vector.